# What is the common/best practice regarding where to place the "lock" to prevent inactive data from being edit?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database

What is the common/best practice regarding where to place the "lock" to prevent inactive data from being edit? For example, invoice records that have already been posted in an Invoice table, inactive contacts in a Contact table, etc.

Do you "lock" it in the business logic but leave it wide open in the database such that any users with access to the database can change those records? Do you lock it at the table level? If so, use trigger? permission?, or?

Comment: I don't think there is a "best" practice.  But a typical method would be to insert the records into a table where no one has update permissions.

Comment: Payed/approved/fixated in closed period **Invoice** and some _inactive contacts_ - totally different cases in my opinion.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if we do that, how do we void an invoice or make record active again?

Comment: @IvanStarostin That's also what I am trying to find out, if there are different practices for different cases. What would be some common practices to handle these two cases?

Comment: Firstly I don't understand what is "inactive contacts" case. Why shouldn't I edit them?

Comment: @IvanStarostin "Inactive contacts" is just one case, it could be any inactive records -- records that I want to keep for historical purpose but they are no longer used and should not be edited. For example, if a person leaves a company, but I want to keep all of their activity history. A customer no longer use our service but I want to keep history, etc.

Comment: I don't know such business rule as "no longer in use" or "inactive". I understand a contract which is expired - which is a simple case, old records of some thechnical data which can be totally removed or moved to some outer storage, a closed period for accounting data which is much more complicated than previous case and "don't edit invoice older than..." - lots of related data must be controlled. Do you have business rules for your cases? Start from there. What is a "customer no longer uses your service"? What if he calls or pays tomorrow? Why can't I edit his contacts info or a typo in name?